# Live migration (kvm) not working if any I/O operation is in progress

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I did this experiment: on VM I started watching a video on youtube.
While video was in progress I started migration.
Migration did not complete until video was not finished.

I did another experiment: I installed a web server on VM.
I then started an httperf stress test.
As before migration did not complete until the stress test was closed.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself...it is just normal as my network was not fast enough.
In order for the migration process to work network has to deliver RAM modifications faster than the actual application writing them.